# 'curl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python-2.7, curl

While executing curl command through `os.system(cmd)` in python script

```
cmd="curl" 
os.system(cmd)
```

> 'curl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Is curl installed on your operating system? This code will attempt to run a program on your OS, if curl isn't installed, the command will fail.

Comment: I am using Windows 10  and curl is already pre-installed in my system

Comment: Please ask your favorite search engine for setting the %PATH% in Python scripts.

Answer (score 0):

your error is pointing out as if curl command is not installed on the host. however if you find it installed then this is PATH variable issue. set PATH variable and rerun your code.

Comment: Curl is installed and i set the path also - C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin

Comment: Now this looks to be in debugging stage, follow few of the steps
1- check if you are able to execute curl --help command from your command line. If that works then you have curl set in your PATH if not set your path properly or try giving full path in your script

Comment: @mkrana can execute curl --help in command prompt, but not in batch file. Any help?